# How to make a video of an iPad (or other tablet) screen

Tags: video, ipad

I have been making some movies of my iPad for promotional videos and they all range from bad to worse in terms of video quality. I have used compact cameras and camcorders with pretty similar results.

Most of the stuff I shoot is AVCHD 1920x1080 at 30fps. The camera is positioned to take in the whole screen of the iPad and little (or nothing) else.

The other day I borrowed a Canon REBEL T2i, thinking that the results were going to be fantastic. They were not. There is a weird strobey effect (NO idea why that would appear *more* with this camera shooting 30fps than with any other one), and the clarity is not great. In fact, it may look better with a $250 Sony pocket camera I have.

Which got me to thinking: I really haven't the slightest idea what I'm doing.

- Should the room be dark or light? Or should there be light coming from some specific direction?
- Should the iPad's brightness be high, medium or low?
- Should the camera be as close to the iPad as possible, while still being able to get focus, or a few feet away?
- Since the DSLR has SO many manual settings, what adjustments should I be trying to make?
- Since the DSLR has interchangeable lenses, what kind of lens is really appropriate for this sort of thing?

I could go on, but I really don't even know the questions to ask. A bit of guidance or orientation or some links to read (that are not 400-page books, unless they are titled "How to Make a Video of a Tablet") would be appreciated.

Comment: http://viewstream.com/blog/index.php/2011/12/how-to-record-an-ipad-screen/

Comment: Related: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/how-do-i-record-a-computer-monitor-without-banding-flickering-with-a-canon-t2i-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I recall

- The room should be dark, so the tablet is the light source.
- Experiment with the brightness, but usually low is the way to go.
- Camera doesn't need to be extremely close, but the more zoom you use the more obvious vibrations will be.
- Put the DSLR in manual focus and adjust it so the tablet is just slightly out of focus - this will remove the moire effect.
- You want a short depth of field. This is achieved with a lower F-Stop (larger aperture opening).

I attended a session by [Hendrik Kueck](http://www.pocketpixels.com/) (creator of [Color Splash](http://www.pocketpixels.com/ColorSplash.html)) at [360iDev](http://360iDev.com) on this topic specifically. It was called "*Effectively using videos to explain and market your app*". You can [buy that video online](http://360idev.com/session-videos#360idevaustin2010) for $3.50. It goes into a lot more detail and explains everything really well (and may even correct me on a couple points.) It is a deal at 10x that price.

Comment: Wow, great stuff, thanks! I will definitely check out the video and go through all of your advice carefully.

Comment: Also I just added a link as a comment to my question a friend sent me...

Comment: @Yar: I was just reading that article. Looks to have some good information too. I am going to be shooting similar video here soon, so am researching this again too.

Comment: a friend has also suggested I try a "softening filter" and "UV filter", i.e., hardware. Thoughts?

Comment: @Yar: I haven't tried. Get that video by Hendrik and I bet he has his email address in it and you could email him. He does a fabulous job on his videos.

Comment: After lots of testing and fiddling with a T2i, I actually got better results with my Sony DSC-WX5. Batteries are cheap and it does AVCHD, but it just contains less artifacts the the Digital Reflex. Weird. Anyway: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bRIa7y4tLM Not 100% pro, of course... anyway, iPad upside down, some ambient light, a nice distance away, and brightness at 50%. It's a 1-minute video only... Still exploring though...

Answer (score 1):

Even better is to use a HDMI capture device like a Blackmagic Intensity. Plug the iPad (or any tablet with HDMI output) into it and away you go. Perfect screen capture.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that you lose the finger (um, that doesn't sound right). It's a reasonable suggestion, though, but the units are $200...

Comment: The finger isn't that important, is it? If anything, the finger/hand gets in the way of seeing what's on the screen. Plus the quality of a capture via HDMI will look perfect, 1:1 copy - where as you've found with a video camera, there's so many variables that can change the quality.

Comment: the finger is pretty important for demoing, otherwise I'd use the iPad Simulator, which is beyond perfect (though hard to pinch and zoom)